# updating ListBox colors in C#

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

for my purposes I am writing a GUI in 4.0 that displays my custom `Instance` objects in a `ListBox` with custom colors. I've been able to draw them in their respective colors, but am wondering if there is a way to change these colors.

I've attempted and went down the route of clearing the `ListBox` and readding the `Instance` objects in a separate `BackGroundWorker` every few seconds, but this route has lead to many headaches with the fact that the `ListBox.selectedIndex` will change and shoot off an event to my `ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler. So I would like to avoid that if possible as it is a nightmare to try to code through with threading, locking, raceconditions, turning event handlers on and off, Invalidargumentexceptions.

I was wondering, is there any way for a backGroundWorker to visually update the colors in my `ListBox` **without the need to add and re-add the items** to trigger the `DrawItem` event as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803064/listbox-insert-items-in-color)?

Edit:
Calling ListBox.Refresh() redrew all the items in the listbox, and doing so, avoided the selectedIndexChanged event handler and updated the Colors of all the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the color and call `ListBox.Update()`, or if from a different thread, `ListBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker( ()=>ListBox.Update() ))`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the background worker report progress, then you can in the progress changed method, access the items in your list box and redraw the one you want, depending on what percentage of progress you reported. Should be fairly simple, unless you have a lot of items and a lot of colors.